# Rename a class using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to rename my class name using jquery but now working.

```
<li id="menulogo" class="menulogo-hide">Logo</li>
```

Here is my code

```
//fixed navigation on top when scrolling
var num = 50; //number of pixels before modifying styles
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
         $('#nav').addClass('fixed-menu');
         $('#menulogo').removeClass('menulogo-view').addClass('menulogo-hide');
    } else {
         $('#nav').removeClass('fixed-menu');
         $('#menulogo').removeClass('menulogo-hide').addClass('menulogo-view'); 
    }
});
```

If I try bellow code its works, it can successfully add the class`fixed-menu`  . see my bellow code looks same but not work failed to add the class

```
var num = 50; //number of pixels before modifying styles
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
          $('#nav').addClass('fixed-menu');
    } else {
         $('#nav').removeClass('fixed-menu');
    }
});
```

The code is not working even it looks same as above . Why its not working.

```
var num = 50; //number of pixels before modifying styles
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
        $('#menulogo').addClass('menulogo');
    } else {
        $('#menulogo').removeClass('menulogo');
    }
});
```

Comment: what you mean _rename class_?

Comment: You don't rename classes. You mean you want to change the class?

Comment: @SuperCool, why you edit your code to code from answer???

Comment: @Grundy I try to implement the answer and showing that the #nav is working but #menulogo is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't toggle multiple classes. Instead, simply use:

```
 $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
         $('#menulogo').removeClass('menulogo-view').addClass('menulogo-hide');
    } else {
         $('#menulogo').removeClass('menulogo-hide').addClass('menulogo-view');
    }
});
```

Comment: [_Add or remove one or **more classes** from each element in the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the value of the state argument._](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Comment: @Grundy Check what's he doing, looks confusing, so instead, let it be straight. It should be either remove or add. Do you understand? His method should be used only once. Say like this: http://pastie.org/private/4sjnmwivuzopnk8ppjhobg

Comment: @Grundy Please let me know if the above comment makes sense for you. `:)`

Comment: @Grundy Moreover, both the functions in both states do the same thing in his class.

Comment: Yep, OP use it wrong, but, he **can** toggle multiple classes

Comment: guys I have update the jquery code in my question. but @PraveenKumar after using your method the `$('#nav').addClass('fixed-menu');` only work . and why the 2nd option is not working? Sorry I am learning jquery

Comment: I am trying to fixed the navigation when scroll and add a logo into the menu

Comment: @SuperCool Try to interchange the `if` and `else` functions whatever I have given?

Comment: @SuperCool What do you mean by not working? Define it.

Comment: @SuperCool Are you giving it inside `$(function () { });`?

Comment: yes if the id `#nav`  can add the class the the `#menulogo` should also work the same way but it does not.

Comment: @SuperCool Can you create your full issue in jsbin.com please? JSBin, not JSFiddle.

Comment: @SuperCool Ha ha... `:)` Welcome!

Comment: @SuperCool Definitely.

Comment: @SuperCool You should have shown this to me before. jQuery is not getting loaded.

Comment: @SuperCool In the file: `http://www.vapepartsmart.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.3`, Remove the last line: `jQuery.noConflict();`

Comment: I have removed but the same only #nav work  but #menulogo not working .. i should die now :(

Comment: @SuperCool No no, please don't die. `:P` Your life is more worth than the JavaScript. `:)` I will look into it and will let you know if there's something else.

Comment: `$('#menulogo')`  changed with `$('li#menulogo')`  and its work  :)